# On the $G$-conjugacy and $C_G(x)$-conjugacy

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group and $S=\{g_{1}, g_{2},...,g_{k}\}$ be a system of representatives for its conjugacy classes. For $1\leq i\leq k$, let  $C_G(g_{i}):=\{x\in G | xg_{i}=g_{i}x \}$ be the centralizer of $g_{i}$.

How could we obtain from $S$ a system of representatives for the conjugacy classes of $C_G(g_{i})$?.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I am really struggling to understand your first paragraph. Firstly $C_G(g_i)$ is the centralizer of the element $g_i$, not of "the conjugacy classes $g_i$" (whatever that means). The next sentence beginning "If two different elements..." seems inconsequential. In any case, it is not true that a system of representatives of the conjugacy classes of $C_G(g_i)$ is a subset of $S$. It is possible that $C_G(g_i)$ has more conjugacy classes than $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt. Thank you very much. Could you provide me an example for which $k(G)< k(C_G(g_{i}))$?.

Comment: The dihedral group of order $10$ has four classes, but the centralizer of an element of order $5$ has five.

Comment: Thank you very much.